# Javascript not being called from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to create a web app that contains several hyperlinks. When a hyperlink is clicked, it is supposed to trigger an alert box (just filler code to see if JS function is being called). My hyperlinks are being generated using this javascript function:

```
function updateAlertList(results) {

    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
    { 
        div.innerHTML += '<p><a class="ra-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc()">' + results[i].alertName + '</a></p>';
    }
}
```

and the JS function that generates the alert is:

```
function myJsFunc(){
    alert('this function was called');
}
```

For some reason, only the LAST hyperlink in the list of hyperlinks will trigger the JS function called myJsFunc. Whenever I click on any of the other hyperlinks that are earlier in the list, the JS function is not called. When I look in the console in Chrome Developer tools, I see the error "Cannot read property 'plugin_dispatchEvent___' of undefined"

Anybody know why the very last hyperlink in my list of hyperlinks works.. but the earlier ones don't?

Comment: Can you try to hard code it first, and determine if that works?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to this:

```
function updateAlertList(results) {

  var div = document.getElementById('output');
  div.innerHTML = '';

  var alrtInnrHTML = '';

  for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
    alrtInnrHTML += '<p><a class="ra-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc()">' + results[i].alertName + '</a></p>';
    console.log('alrtInnrHTML: ' + alrtInnrHTML);
    }
}

div.innerHTML = alrtInnrHTML;
```

Please note that I created a variable `alrtInnrHTML`, and using `+=` on the variable, not the innerHTML.
You are trying to use `+=` on DOM manipulation instead of a variable.  Set the HTML text string first, then inject the entire string just one time.  Right now you are injecting HTML into the same DIV over and over and over again.  Do all the links show up?  In any case, even if your logic is working, I would change the logic to what I am suggesting, check that the final HTML content is correct with a `console.log()` output, and then inject the HTML all at once.

You would actually be better off adding individual `<p>` and `<a>` tags in each loop, and adding HTML in each loop rather than trying to construct a string of HTML.

You might want to do some reading about:

- `insertRow`
- `insertCell`
- `setAttribute`
- `textContent`
- `createTextNode`
- `appendChild`
- `createElement`

With those methods you could avoid writing long HTML strings for the most part.
For example, you could create a table, with a new row for every result.

```
for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) { 
  window.row1 = tblAlertList.insertRow(-1);
  window.cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
  row1.setAttribute("class", "ra-button");
  row1.innerHTML = <p><a class="ra-button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc()">' + results[i].alertName + '</a></p>';
}
```

That above code is just to give you an idea of what you might do, it's not working code.

Instead of creating a table, you could create an unordered list:  `<ul>`

```
div.innerHTML = "<ul><a></a></ul>";
```

Then append a child to the last node in the list:

```
var node=document.createElement("LI");
var textnode=document.createTextNode("New Alert");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```